# CDC and CreateCompatibleDC and wglMakeCurrent, not what i expect

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

So I am trying to create a CBitmap by loading it into a CDC and drawing onto it.

[MSDN example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxzck32.aspx)
;

Somewhere in beginning of program(this is where we make m_hGLRC)

```
CDC *dc = GetDCEx(NULL, DCX_CACHE);
HGLRC m_hGLRC = wglCreateContext(dc->m_hDC);
```

Our regular working CView Draw

```
CPaintDC pDC(someCView);
bResult = wglMakeCurrent(pDC.m_hDC, m_hGLRC);
```

bResult is always true and we start drawing into this CPaintDC.

WHAT I try to do.

```
CClientDC cliDC(sameCViewAsAbove);
CDC dcMem;
dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(cliDC); // This returns true. everything looks good. 

bResult = wglMakeCurrent(dcMem.m_hDC, m_hGLRC);
if(!bResult)
{
    int err = GetLastError();  // I hit this and err == 2000(ERROR_INVALID_PIXEL_FORMAT)
}
```

wglMakeCurrent returns False and err == ERROR_INVALID_PIXEL_FORMAT...
I figured dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(someClientDC); where someClientDC was create out of the same CView we always use to draw would create an actually compatible DC.

I have tried with a CPaintDC instead of a CClientDc and same result.

NOTE: this works fine...no errors.

```
CClientDC cliDC(sameCViewAsAbove);
bResult = wglMakeCurrent(cliDC.m_hDC, m_hGLRC);
```

So if my dcMem is created out of the cliDc, and the cliDC is compatible, why would dcMem not work?

Comment: Well, where is your actual pixel format setup? There is a special flag you should be using for this (`PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP`), otherwise you absolutely have an invalid pixel format for the task at hand.

Comment: @Andon - Thank you. I did not think changing my pixel format was necessary since i was using a ClientDC that was compatible, to 'CreateCompatibleDC' from it. I have not found the solution yet, but I have realized the pixel format is wrong. I would accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Rather than trying to find the solution yourself, you should edit your question to show a little bit more code (particularly the pixel format). I actually would not feel comfortable writing an answer that is not an actual answer...

Comment: I'd like to throw in that creating OpenGL contexts on Bitmap DCs will always result in getting a software fallback OpenGL-1.1 that is very slow. What you should really do it create a OpenGL context on a hidden window, generate a Framebuffer Object, render to that and read the result to a DIBSECTION using glReadPixels.